# Можно ли обойтись одним setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, settimeout

**Задача:** При переходе на страницу отображается число 19, через 10 секунд к числу добавляется +1 единица, и каждые 5 минут пребывания на странице число увеличивается еще на +2 единицы.
**HTML:**

```
<div class="counter">19</div>
<div>sales</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const target = document.querySelector(".counter");

let t1 = 10000,
    t2 = 300000;

const updateCounter = function () {
    let count = Number(target.innerHTML);

    target.innerHTML = count += 1;
};

setTimeout(updateCounter, t1);

const counter = function () {
    let count = Number(target.innerHTML);

    target.innerHTML = count += 2;
};
setInterval(counter, t2);
```

**Вопрос:** Можно ли обойтись одним setInterval без setTimeout? Или есть способ написать код намного проще?
**P.S.** Это мои первые шаги в JS поэтому  не судите строго.

Comment: "Можно ли обойтись одним setInterval без setTimeout?" --- можно, но смысла не имеет. Лучше сделать раздельную логику и назвать методы "говоряще". Т.е. имеет смысл скорее сделать рефактор в области понимания кода другими разрабами.. А делать один"божественный" метод нет смысла

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись одной функцией с повторением `setTimeout()`, но, как вам уже написали, это без нужды запутает логику функции и добавит в неё лишние проверки. Так что разве что в качестве упражнения:

```js
const target = document.querySelector(".counter");

let t1 = 10000,
    t2 = 300000;

const updateCounter = function () {
    let count = Number(target.innerHTML);

    target.innerHTML = count += (count === 19 ? 1 : 2);
    
    setTimeout(updateCounter, t2);
};

setTimeout(updateCounter, t1);
```

```html
<div class="counter">19</div>
<div>sales</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Значит мой вариант вполне даже можно использовать, да?

Comment: @Marty По-моему, да)